# scapy's exported linux cooked-mode capture doesn't open in wireshark

Tags: python, wireshark, pcap, scapy

Here is a simple exmaple:

```
from scapy.all import *
pkts = rdpcap('/tmp/sample.pcap')
wireshark(pkts)
```

Then wireshark gives this error:

```
The capture file appears to be damaged or corrupt.
(libpcap: IrDA capture has a packet with an invalid sll_protocol field)
```

I am using wireshark 1.8, python 2.7.3 and scapy 2.2.0.

NOTE: I can open the smaple.pcap file  using wireshark directly.

What can I do to make scapy-generated pcap files to open in wireshark?

**EDIT:**
I tried other pcap files (from wireshark capture samples) and it worked. It seems the problem is in my packets. Here is the first packet (which don't work also):

```
###[ cooked linux ]###
  pkttype   = unicast
  lladdrtype= 0x1
  lladdrlen = 6
  src       = '\x00\x04\xed\xcb\x9b0'
  proto     = 0x800
###[ IP ]###
     version   = 4L
     ihl       = 5L
     tos       = 0xb8
     len       = 165
     id        = 47433
     flags     = 
     frag      = 0L
     ttl       = 49
     proto     = udp
     chksum    = 0x50c9
     src       = 22.31.32.55
     dst       = 192.168.1.102
     \options   \
###[ UDP ]###
        sport     = 4566
        dport     = 4566
        len       = 145
        chksum    = 0x0
###[ Raw ]###
           load      = 'H\x84\x80\x80\x80\x80\x80\x8c\x80\x80\x86\x81\x8b\x82\x80\x82\x81\x98\xb1\xb9\xb2\xae\xb1\xb6\xb8\xae\xb1\xae\xb2\xb5\xad\xb0\xb1\xb2\xb2\xb6\xb6\xb5\xb7\xb4\xb9\xb4\xad\x81\xca\x82\x89\xb9\xb9\xb5\xb0\xb6\xb1\xb0\xb3\xb3\xa6\x81\x80\xa7\x81\x80\xa8\x82\x80\x80\x84\x89\xb9\xb9\xb5\xb0\xb6\xb1\xb0\xb3\xb3\x8a\x82\xe5\xee\x86\x88\xe3\xe3\xec\xe9\xe5\xee\xf4\xb2\x89\x84\x80\x80\x81\x80\xb8\x89\x80\x80\x80\x80\x80\x80\x80\x81\x80\x88\x84\x80\x80\x81\x80\xb7\x89\x80\x80\x80\x80\x80\x80\x80\x81\x80\x8c\x82\x80\x82\x9f\x84\x9e\xa7 \xe2\xb6\x80'
```

*Note: changed IP addresses so checksum might not be correct.*

Comment: Does `wireshark([pkts[0]])` work? If it does, try finding the problematic packet. If it doesn't, edit your question with the value of `pkts[0]`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have no idea what seems to be the problem, but it can be resolved in the following manner:

```
wireshark(pkt for pkt in pkts) # don't supply a list but rather a generator
```

This also outputs the following message:

> WARNING: PcapWriter: unknown LL type for generator. Using type 1 (Ethernet)

Apparently, the `wireshark` function doesn't handle a [Linux cooked-mode capture](https://www.wireshark.org/lists/ethereal-users/200412/msg00314.html) that well. This odd situation might have something to do with the following excerpt from [`scapy`'s wiki](http://bb.secdev.org/scapy/wiki/doc/ViewingPacketsWithWireshark):

> Please remember that Wireshark works with Layer 2 packets (usually called "frames"). So we had to add an `Ether()` header to our ICMP packets. Passing just IP packets (layer 3) to Wireshark will give strange results.

We can also circumvent this issue by creating a dummy Ethernet layer, if we don't really care about the layer 2 frame:

```
pkts = [Ether(src=pkt[0].src)/pkt[1:] for pkt in pkts]
```

---

**EDIT -** upon further research, and analyzing scapy's source code, I figured out why passing a generator object seems to solve this issue.

The `wireshark` function creates a temporary file containing the packets and launches Wireshark with that file. The link type to be specified in the header of that file is extracted in the following manner:

```
if self.linktype == None:
    if type(pkt) is list or type(pkt) is tuple or isinstance(pkt,BasePacketList):
        pkt = pkt[0]
    try:
        self.linktype = conf.l2types[pkt.__class__]
    except KeyError:
        warning("PcapWriter: unknown LL type for %s. Using type 1 (Ethernet)" % pkt.__class__.__name__)
        self.linktype = 1
```

When passing a generator object, the first `if` statement evaluates to `False` (which is obviously a bug) and an exception is raised when attempting to access `conf.l2types[pkt.__class__]` since `pkt.__class__` is `<type 'generator'>`. Therefore, the except clause of the `try-except` code block is executed and the link type is specified as 1.

However, when passing a real list, the first `if` statement evaluates to `True` and the first packet of the list is extracted and used to access `conf.l2types`, which is:

```
In [2]: conf.l2types
Out[2]: 
   0x1 <-  Dot3                 (802.3)
   0x1 <-> Ether                (Ethernet)
   0xc  -> IP                   (IP)
  0x17  -> Ether                (Ethernet)
  0x1f <-> IPv6                 (IPv6)
  0x65 <-> IP                   (IP)
  0x69 <-> Dot11                (802.11)
  0x71  -> CookedLinux          (cooked linux)
  0x77 <-> PrismHeader          (Prism header)
  0x7f <-> RadioTap             (RadioTap dummy)
  0x90 <-> CookedLinux          (cooked linux)
  0xc0 <-> PPI                  (Per-Packet Information header (partial))
 0x304  -> Ether                (Ethernet)
 0x321  -> Dot11                (802.11)
 0x322  -> PrismHeader          (Prism header)
 0x323  -> RadioTap             (RadioTap dummy)
```

Since `pkts[0].__class__` is `scapy.layers.l2.CookedLinux`, the link type is set to `0x90` rather than to `0x71` (seems like yet another bug), which results in Wireshark failing to parse the file.

---

Therefore, I think that the best approach would be to copycat scapy's `wireshark` function, with the subtle change of allowing the user to explicitly specify the link type:

```
def wireshark(*args, **kwargs):
    """Run wireshark on a list of packets"""
    f = scapy.all.get_temp_file()
    scapy.all.wrpcap(f, *args, **kwargs)
    subprocess.Popen([scapy.all.conf.prog.wireshark, "-r", f])

wireshark(pkts, linktype=0x71)
```

---

**EDIT -** I've now noticed that the link type mapping issue was already [reported and fixed](http://bb.secdev.org/scapy/issue/5081/wrpcap-writes-linux-cooked-sll-frames-with) by secdev. However, it hasn't reached `python-scapy` just yet. I've also created [a new issue](https://bitbucket.org/secdev/scapy/issue/5111/pcapwriter-doesnt-handle-a-generator) on the invalid handling of a generator object in `PcapWriter`.

Answer (score 0):

> (libpcap: IrDA capture has a packet with an invalid sll_protocol field)

Linux IrDA uses something *like* the Linux cooked-mode header, but it's not the same:

- [Linux cooked-mode header](http://www.tcpdump.org/linktypes/LINKTYPE_LINUX_SLL.html), with a link-layer header type of 113;
- [Linux IrDA header](http://www.tcpdump.org/linktypes/LINKTYPE_LINUX_IRDA.html), with a link-layer header type of 144.

I don't know what caused your program to choose 144 rather than 113; was your *input* file an Linux IrDA file rather than a Linux cooked capture file?